# How do I execute the same code on both page load and on an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to simplyfy this js/jquery Code? Like merging the events or something?

The goal is to have just one `// code` remaining. Both are exactly the same, but I need to execute it one time when the page has loaded and then after every keyup or change event in form fields with class `.search`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // code
    $(".search").on('keyup change' , function(){
       // same code
   });
});
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){` can be replaced with `$(function(){`.

Comment: It's already merged events.

Comment: Are you asking how to simplify the code you've shown? Or the code that's implied by "// code" and "'// same code"

Comment: Put the "same code" in a function on its own, and call that function before setting it to an event handler.

Comment: @procrastinator Depends where your code is placed it can be two different behaviors. domready waits for DOM to "ready", while `$(function)` will executes as soon as it's reached by parser

Comment: @Justinas I'm afraid that you are wrong : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3 :-| Anyway, I'm off-topic.

Comment: @Justinas Actually also `$(document).ready(...)` is executed immediately when met by parser, but the callback passed to both functions will not be run before the DOM is ready.

Comment: The goal is to have just one `// code` remaining. Both are exactly the same, but i need to execute it one time when the page has loaded and than after every keyup or change event in form fields with class search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define function to call it twice or more

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function myFunc() {
        // some code
    }

    $(".search").on('keyup change', function(){
        myFunc(); // call on event
    });

    myFunc(); // call on doc. ready
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Plug yourself into a global event like so:

```
var someFunction = function(){
   // some code
}
$(document).on('keyup change', ".search", someFunction);
someFunction()
```